# Functions - Variables - Scope

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

I have the below code.

```
a = 10
def f(x):
    return x + a
a = 3
f(1)
```

If we print(f1) the result is 4. It seems that the second assignment of a is used here (a=3). Could someone explain to me if there is a particular reason or rule for not using the first assignment (a=10)?

Thank you,

Dimitrios

Comment: There is only one variable called `a` here, that was initially set to 10, but you set it to 3 before you called `f`.

Comment: Function body is not executed until the function is actually called.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `x` are resolved each time `return x + a` is executed. You reassign `a` before calling `f`. `f` knows that `a` is not a local variable so looks up "a" in its enclosing scope. That "a" has a `3` in it, and that is what is used.

As a general rule, it would be very bad for `f` to use the original assignment when its executed. That would mean that functions couldn't take advange of global variables changing. It would also require that global variables be assigned before the function is even defined, which is not particularly useful for a dynamic language.

You can hack it, though. If you define a  parameter with a default value, it will be assigned when the function is defined and you get what you want.

```
a = 10
def f(x, a=a):
    return x + a
a = 3
print(f(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You see, you've defined a before you **defined** f(x). But your **call** to f(1) was after you assigned the value 3 to "a".

f(x) will always use the **current** value of "a" when it its called, not when it is defined. If you want a constant value for "a" inside f(x), you should declare it inside the function, something like:

```py
def f(x):
    a = 10
    return x + a
```